# Rails server runs, but not all browsers actually show the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, browser

I'm developing a Rails 4 app on Mac OS 10.6.8, and yesterday I started getting errors -- but only in certain browsers, and for certain URLs.

Everything looks fine in the Terminal:

```
$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-02-24 12:43:47] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-02-24 12:43:47] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
[2014-02-24 12:43:47] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=41543 port=3000
```

But `http://0.0.0.0:3000/` in Chrome or Safari produces a 403 error:

```
403 Forbidden
hefishkUtZiafopyoshGeOnnIbDoufye
```

That address opens in Firefox, though.

I also tried another address, `http://localhost:3000/`. Previously, Chrome displayed "No data received" with a frowny face and two buttons, "Reload" and "More". Now it works fine in Chrome. It also works in Safari and Firefox.

Opening `http://127.0.0.1:3000` works in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

This is more of a bump in the road than a blockade, but its randomness is troubling. I don't think I substantially changed my Rails app in the meantime. I even created a new Rails project and got the same error messages.

Also, I've seen other questions on SO where all three addresses suddenly don't work, and just as suddenly start working again later. I'd like to know if there's a better fix than just waiting.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0.0.0.0` means rails is listening on all interfaces on your box.

When you're accessing the application, pick a specific one (`localhost` / `127.0.0.1` or your actual IP (you'll have multiple IPs if you have more than one physical or virtual network interface).

Comment: Picking 127.0.0.1 as a specific IP seems to work, at least for now. I hope it continues to do so. But why wouldn't 0.0.0.0:3000 work? It's what the terminal says to use, and I haven't had any issues with it until recently.

Comment: Because 0.0.0.0 is not a valid target address.  That address is essentially the network address for "everyone."  Your host will not respond to it.

Comment: Some browsers will autocorrect 0.0.0.0 to localhost but it's a moot point - you shouldn't be accessing your website on 'every available network interface'

Comment: OK then, I'll stick to using localhost or 127.0.0.1.